# Automatic Serial Number Generator Using EJS Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, ejs

I want to Generate Automatic Serial number for my Registered Admins

```
<tbody>
<% Admins.forEach(function (Admin){ %>
    <tr>
        <td>//S.No Here Starts from 1 //</td>
        <td><%= Admin.First_Name %></td>
        <td><%= Admin.Last_Name %></td>
        <td><%= Admin.User_Name %></td>
        <td><%= Admin.Email %></td>
        <td><%= Admin.Password %></td>
        <td><%= Admin.Contact %></td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: Won't get much help if you don't properly explain your problem and ask informative questions. Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` passes the `index` as the second argument. It's zero-based so you'll need to add 1:

```
<% Admins.forEach(function (Admin, index) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
```

Comment: Yup buddy Thank You